# Selecting media item in Android Auto Queue does nothing

Tags: android, android-auto

I am adding support for playback on Android Auto to my app. I have successfully created my Service which extends MediaBrowserServiceCompat and all works fine. Within Android Auto, I can click on a MediaItem to play and playback starts. On the "now playing" screen, if I then tap the playlist/queue button I see the following logs:

```
D/GH.UnCfbMediaActivity: openQueue
D/GH.MediaModel: unsubscribe mediaId=QUEUE_ROOT
D/GH.UnCfbMediaActivity: subscribeCFAdapterToQueue
D/GH.MediaModel: subscribe mediaId=QUEUE_ROOT
unsubscribe mediaId=QUEUE_ROOT
D/GH.VnActivity: disableInteraction
D/GH.MediaModel: Loaded 10 children for QUEUE_ROOT.
```

The current queue is shown (with the 10 MediaItems I expect to see) and I tap on a MediaItem in the queue, Android Auto returns to the "now playing" screen but doesn't play the MediaItem I selected in the queue. I expected to see another call to the `onPlayFromMediaId()` method within my Service but there's no callback whatsoever. This means I can't change the song playing by selecting an item in the queue.

I'm obviously missing something but I can't figure it out. All help appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Answer found! `MediaSessionCompat.Callback` has a method `onSkipToQueueItem(long id)` which is called once a `MediaItem` in the current queue is selected. Override this method and you'll be notified when a queue item is selected.